# Questions of the type "suppose each vertex has degree divisible by..."

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, divisibility

> Let $G$ be a graph in which each vertex has degree divisible by four.
>   Prove or disprove that there's a subgraph $G^\prime$ on the same
>   vertex set such that the degrees in $G^\prime$ are half the original
>   degrees.

The previous part asked to do the same for degrees divisible by 2, and there, a triangle works because the sum of degrees is even. But here, I'm clueless... How to translate the divisibility information into anything geometric?

Comment: Do you see why the given construction works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick $H$ a connected component of $G$, we must only show that a subgraph of $H$ with the desired properties exists.

The number of edges in $H$ is half of the sum of the degrees in $H$, since this sum is a multiple of $4$, the number of edges in $H$ is even.

Since all of the degrees in $H$ are even there exists an eulerian circuit $e_1,e_2,\dots e_{2m}$ of $H$, the subgraph we want is the one that contains the edges with even index.

Comment: Very cool! I'll remember that even degrees should get me thinking about Eulerian circuits.